# Changing column name in yii cgridview based on database value

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I am stuck in a situation where I have to change the column header based on database value. e.g If database value is 1, column name should be 'Kick Off', If its 2 then column name should be 'Tip Off'. I used following code but its not working.

```
array(
    'name' => 'date', 
    'header' => '($data->league_id==1) ? "Kick Off" : "Tip Off"',
    'type' => 'raw',
    'value' => 'strtoupper(date("D M d", strtotime($data->date)))',
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see [`CDataColumn`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn) (default if you use an array to specify the attributes), the header value is a string and will not be evaluated as a PHP expression.

If you take a look at CDataColumn's [`renderHeaderCellContent()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#renderHeaderCellContent-detail) method, you will notice that it uses the attribute name from the model.

```
$this->grid->dataProvider->model->getAttributeLabel($this->name)
```

So I don't see any problem with placing this in your model, which is where it should have belonged in the first place:

```
public function attributeLabels() {
    return array(
        'date' => '($this->league_id == 1) ? "Kick Off" : "Tip Off"',
        ...
```

Comment: I tried but $this->league_id is empty so it always returns 'Tip Off'. I also tried other attributes like $this->id to compare but it is also empty. I don't know why as it should not be.

Comment: The model has relations with other models but league_id attribute resides in the same table. Match Schedule table has match schedule for different leagues with date and time. On showing schedule for certain league, I need to show team names and start date and time. I need to change the (date) header based on league id.